# How to change --background ion-content color dynamically

Tags: angular, ionic4

I would like to change the `--background` color style property dynamically in ionic 4.
This is my attempt:

```
<ion-content [class]="ionContentClass">
  <a (click)="changeColor1()">Change color 1</a>
  <a (click)="changeColor1()">Change color 1</a>
</ion-content>
```

and I change it with:

```
changeColor1() {
  this.ionContentClass = "ionContentColor1"
}
changeColor2() {
  this.ionContentClass = "ionContentColor2"
}
```

Then in the css:

```
.ionContentColor1 {
  --background: #000;
}
.ionContentColor1 {
  --background: #fff;
}
```

But it doesn't work, the application seems to break. Is there a standard approach to achieve this?

Comment: Test css classes before applying the function, I think you need to add the css class in the highest level global.scss and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are properly telling angular that a value has changed.

Angular is responsible for updating the rendered template (dom) with the values populated from your component, however when you change a value directly without letting angular know that it was updated it never re-renders the dom.

You can fix this a number of ways, either making the value a `Subject` and subscribing to it in the html (I recommend BehaviorSubject or ReplaySubject) or importing the `changeDetectorRef` and telling angular changes were made

Comment: I'm new to angular, could you maybe provide me a simple example or reference? Unfortunately I cannot follow, but thank you very much for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an issue because Ionic uses Css variables now. ;)

You can also change the background of ion-content by adding color property to it:

```
<ion-content color="primary">
```

The reasons for which this is the desired behavior, explains **@brandyscarney** here:

[ion-content background can't be set with css background property](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/15849#issuecomment-427081054)

Also, try this.

```
<ion-content padding [ngClass]="{ 'bg-red': changeColorVariableFromComponent }">
   ...
</ion-content>
```

and let me know it's working for you.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

use this code to set background color dynamically

```
<ion-content style="--background: {{classobject.color_name_or_code}};--ion-text-color: #000;">
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/late-answers/26207780)